# systemctl nmbd service disabled

Tags: networking, server, samba

Sorry for newbie question:

I wanted to connect to the samba server and accidentally followed a protocol to create a samba share (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-samba-share-for-a-small-organization-on-ubuntu-16-04):
I used the following commands, as it says in the tutorial:
"Both the Samba server smbd and the Samba NetBIOS server nmbd are installed and started. nmbd is not required for this tutorial, so in the interests of security you can stop and disable it with systemctl."

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo systemctl stop nmbd.service
sudo systemctl disable nmbd.service
sudo systemctl stop smbd.service
```

Can I redo these commands, without breaking anything?
Do I have to stop samba from running these services every time I boot?
Or should I deinstall Samba?
Cheers!

Comment: the "stop" directive does it for now. the "disable" directive means it will not try to start by itself, even after re-boot. Typically you can stop and start or restart or reload a service several times.

Comment: Thank you, Doug!